# vonage publish insertDefaultUI and mirror options

Tags: javascript, opentok, vonage

i can't find any info on that

publish options insertDefaultUI set to false and mirror set to true do not work together?

```
const publisher = OT.initPublisher({
  insertDefaultUI: false,
  mirror: true
});

publisher.on({
  videoElementCreated: (e) => {
    $('#video-preview').append(e.element);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself, just do it in css ...

```
   #video-preview {
     -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
      -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
      -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
      transform: scaleX(-1);
   }
```